# Ubuntu 12.10 in VMware Player pointer problems

Tags: 12.10, virtualbox, vmware

Ubuntu 12.10 works flawlessly in VMware Player 5.0.2 except for one major issue - cursor is rendered in the wrong location (a pixel, or so, to the left and to the top; same thing observed in VirtualBox):

[image: screenshot]

This wouldn't bother me so much if that didn't actually cause some things to misbehave (in VMware Player only, VirtualBox is fine).

Whenever I try to use a scrollbar, I have to carefully press it, move the pointer away from the edge, and then scroll, because otherwise (if I keep the cursor at the edge) it just won't get properly detected, and the scrollbar will jump semi-randomly. Same thing happens on the left edge as well.

Another 'kind of' related issue is that I use a trackpoint and when I hold the middle button - I can't scroll (while in VirtualBox I can).

Possibly useful info:

- Host: Windows 8 64bit
- Machine: ThinkPad T530
- CPU: i7-3720QM (supports virtualization)
- GPU: HD4000
- Resolution: 1920x1080